# Failing python unit tests on self hosted runner through Github Actions

Tags: pytest, github-actions, tpu

I have attached a TPU VM as a self hosted runner to run unit tests through Github Actions. The tests have been failing with core dumped on the pytest command. It is confirmed the tests run successfully if manually ran on the VM, they just fail with `Error: Process completed with exit code 134` if ran through Github Actions.

I have tried running the tests in my VM, the tests are running successfully when manually run using the same environment.

Comment: Did you check the logs why it failed and the location that error is coming form?